# Sending file from S3 to third party FTP server using CloudFront

Tags: ftp, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have some files that are stored on S3.
On users request, I want to transfer them to FTP server of a third party site.
Amazon S3 does not support FTP/SFTP.

Currently I am downloading the file from S3 to my local server using S3 APIs and then transferring it to third party FTP server.

S3 --API--> Local --FTP--> Third party FTP

Now, instead I want to transfer the files directly to third party FTP server directly from S3 without downloading it to my local server.

S3 ---CloudFront or Other Service---> Third Party FTP

How can I do it using cloudfront or any other services?
Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to do this programatically? Is it a one-off transfer or will you have to do repeatedly?

Comment: Yes I want to do it programatically and I want to do it repeatedly. Whenever user request for file I have to upload that file to his server.

Comment: unfortunately I don't think this is possible. The only way to get a file from S3 is via the API or a Direct Url. The only suggestions I have are to get the user to pull the file from a url or use EC2 as the 'proxy' server. Transfers from S3 to EC2 are very quick and there are no extra bandwidth charges.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'd love to hear it, since I have a very similar (if not the same) requirement. This is my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8403401/291915

Comment: +1 to hear whether you found a solution

Answer (score 1):

S3 only has APIs to get data to it and from it. It also has an API function to copy data between two buckets, but that's about it.

If you require to transfer data from S3 to other places and want to save the download from S3 to your local machine I suggest you start a t1.micro instance and put a script on it to download the files to it (you won't pay the bandwidth because between S3 and EC2 instance on the same region you don't pay anything and its significantly faster) and then upload from that instance to the remote 3rd party FTP site.