# Choosing cloud storage service with web API can FTP third party server

Tags: ftp, amazon-s3, dropbox, dropbox-api, cloud-storage

I need to find a storage service that can programatically (REST API) send (FTP) a file to a third party service. I was thinking of using Amazon S3, but I found a previous similar question here: [Sending file from S3 to third party FTP server using CloudFront](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4859509/291915) and apparently it cant be done.

What I want to avoid is downloading the file to my app server and then upload it to the third party server. I want to send a command to the storage server to send it directly to the third party server.

If I can't find a storage service that delivers this functionality, pricing is my second priority.

Right now I'm thinking either box.net, sugarsync or dropbox, as well as amazon S3 since all of these provide a REST API I can use.

Thank you for your help!